# See what com ports an application is calling?

Tags: windows, serial-port

I have an application in windows, that opens a com port. It attempts to call a comport, then fails and prompts me with an error.

The issue is this is very legacy software that we no longer have the source code for. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way that can trace, or follow a program calling a com port to find out what com port its attempting to allocate.

Comment: [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx)

Comment: Portmon can't connect to ports in windowsXP.

Comment: I've used it myself - it works fine on XP

Comment: When I start it up capture is greyed out. I haven't found a computer that it will work on.

Comment: Is there a dependency that needs to be installed?

Comment: Try running as Administrator

Answer (score 1):

Appearantly you can use Process Explorer (as called out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197/how-do-i-determine-which-process-is-using-a-serial-port)) to search for processes using serial ports.  It sounds like you should be able to use the same searching concept called out the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197/how-do-i-determine-which-process-is-using-a-serial-port) to find what you need.

Comment: The problem is this tells me what ports are active, not what ports are being called. The program fails after it fails to open an unknown port. Since the port isn't opened by the program I can't view it in process explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I actually gave up on this solution and re-wrote the entire program in a week, it had to be done due to binary compatibility issues with the PCI cards.