# The process cannot access the port 'COM4' because it is being used by another process

Tags: vb.net, sms, gsm

I am trying to send sms through gsm modem using vb.net winform application. But when i try to send sms it throws the error

> The process cannot access the port 'COM4' because it is being used by another process.

i tried to check but there is no way i can find which process is using com4.

anyone else ever faced this problem? any solutions regarding this issue?
Regards

Comment: Assuming you aren't doing something wrong in your code itself, Joe's answer is about it. The next time I run into this, I'll try Process Explorer. Some other app may be trying to talk to the modem as well. Maybe a touchscreen for example is set up on that port. Could be a variety of things.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: [How do I determine which process is using a serial port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197/how-do-i-determine-which-process-is-using-a-serial-port)

If that doesn't work, I had that happen before and basically I just renamed the device I was trying to access to another COM port number and then tried again.  If it is actively being used by another process then you'll probably get an error from the application that was using it.