# how to know which Hiprocess has opened the COM port

Tags: c#

I am running to "Access denied" errors while trying to access a COM port?I want to findout who is using the COM port and kill that process?This has been a long pending problem for me,any pointers/suggestions are very much appreciated

```
could not open port 'COM11': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly strike me as a programming question.  Is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine which process is using a serial port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197/how-do-i-determine-which-process-is-using-a-serial-port)

Comment: Try Serial Port Monitor (http://www.aggsoft.com/serial-port-monitor.htm). If you try to open this port the program will show the process that opened this port. If it will show "system" then it is a driver or something similar.